# How to make Sequential step slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-objects, dom-events

I want to make slider with 3 positions 0 50 100 and I want to make restrictions for required every position of the slider with confirmation message?

```
<input type='range'>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the `step`, `min` and `max` attributes:

```html
<input type="range" max="100" min="0" step="50">
```

Comment: I have the following problem I want you to go through every step of the slider so that you can not get from position 0 to go directly to position 100 needing 1 to go from 0 to position 50 and then to position 100.

Comment: as you mentioned "i want to make slider with 3 positions 0 50 100 ", so `step = "50"` will make each slider to go from 0 to 50 to 100.

Comment: Try catching the mousedown event and prevent the default action.